# Read character by character in a csv file in Python

Tags: csv

I am have this situation:

Consider I have a csv file containing something like this

*roger,123\n
mike,234\n
july,102*

I know how to take only the data after comma, but I would like to take each character separetedly, for example:

```
import csv
fd = open("nomes_id.csv", "r")
my_reader = csv.reader(fd)
for row in my_reader:
    print(row[1])
```

With that I print I get something like this:

*123
234
102*

But if I want to get only the first character of each line?

Thank you for all help.

Comment: You mean `print(row[0][0])` (first character of first column)? Or perhaps `print(row[1][0])` (first character of second column)?

Comment: Remember to always tag your question with the language you are using -- [tag:python] in this case.

Comment: @costaparas, thank you a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.